# How to programmatically remove the preview file of react-dropzone-uploader when submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm using `react-dropzone-uploader` along with `formik`. The user will then fill out fields and upload a photo. Rather than using `react-dropzone-uploader`'s own `onSubmit` handler, I use formik, with a different `button` for submitting.

The problem is, I need the preview of `react-dropzone-uploader` to disappear after the user clicks on the submit button. I've used `formik`'s built-in `resetForm` function, but the preview still persists after submission.

Comment: why don't you just make a state that the default value is true but on submitting turn to false and show dropzone with respect to that state, I know this is not optimised solution but this will do the work.

Comment: How about overriding PreviewComponent to null?